# Python 2.7.3: Take an item from a list and make it a key in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to take items from a list and put them into a dictionary.

Say we have the following

```
carList = set(zip(carWordList, carWordFreq))
```

note: I use set to remove duplicates

So carList would produce the following:

```
set([('merry', 3), ('cop', 25), ('completely', 21), ('jaw', 2), ('fiddle', 1), ('bright', 4), ('593', 1), ('asked', 22), ('additionally', 4), ('pretend', 1), ('beam', 4)])
```

Now I want to take the words (ex. 'merry') and make them keys in a dictionary (newDic) with the numbers as values.

Also, I want to use that new dictionary to create another dictionary (otherDic) that has two keys (one being the word (ex. 'merry') and another being "Car", which will take a value later

```
for key in newDic:
    otherDic = [key]["Car"]
```

I tried to do the following:

```
for key in carList:
    otherDic = [key]["Car"]
```

However, I get the following error:

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: You do not seem to understand how dictionaries work. A dictionary cannot have two keys.

Comment: Why don't you change the `zip` order around and just use `dict(carList)`?

Comment: Please add sample input and  final desired output.

Comment: Sorry I meant a dictionary within a dictionary when talking about two keys

Comment: I'll try the suggestions, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this

```
otherDic = [key]["Car"]
```

You are just creating a list `[key]` that contains only `key`, and then you are trying to index it with `"Car"` instead of with an integer, which is why you get the error.

Secondly, you can't start looping into this `for key in newDic:` without ever creating the `newDic` which I don't see you doing at any point.

Anyway, this is the wrong way to approach your problem. To turn your `set` into a dictionary you can simply do this:

```
my_dict = {key: value for key, value in carList}
```

That's called dictionary comprehension by the way. But as @Adam Smith pointed out, that is actually equivalent to

```
my_dict = dict(carList)
```

Which is simpler... But after that, I don't quite understand what you mean by creating another dict with 2 keys per value. You can't create a dict with 2 keys, that's not how they work. You could comment here on the desired output of this new dict and I will edit my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use dictionary comprehension:

```
In [61]: l = set([('merry', 3), ('cop', 25), ('completely', 21), ('jaw', 2), ('fiddle', 1), ('bright', 4), ('593', 1), ('asked', 22), ('additionally', 4), ('pretend', 1), ('beam', 4)])

In [63]: d = {k:v for k,v in l}

In [64]: d
Out[64]:
{'593': 1,
 'additionally': 4,
 'asked': 22,
 'beam': 4,
 'bright': 4,
 'completely': 21,
 'cop': 25,
 'fiddle': 1,
 'jaw': 2,
 'merry': 3,
 'pretend': 1}
```